# Angular - Check if observable is loaded or not

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngxs

I am calling an observable which takes some time in order to resolve, I added a condition to check whether we get a valid result or not (it works fine but it seems to me that shouldn't be done this way).

The code:

```
this.store.select(state => this.list = state.list)
  .subscribe(result => {
    //Without checking if result exists, it throws here undefined, only solution found so far is to add the check below
    if (result) {
     console.log('result is loaded');

      this.copyOfList = [...this.list];
      for (const item of result) {
        this.itemCategories(item.category);
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: are you doing anything else other than `this.list = state.list`

Comment: I am using `this.list` elsewhere

Comment: @brk no, nothing, as it's on the code above

Comment: I am asking are you doint anything inside the `subscription`

Comment: @brk I've updated the code, please check it

Comment: You can use skipWhile() operator

Comment: Are you using `Ngrx`? If so I think you are doing something wrong in `select` method

Comment: Using `NGXS` not `NGRX`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use skipWhile:

```
this.store.select(state => this.list = state.list).pipe(skipWhile(x => !!x))
  .subscribe(result => {

  });
```

Comment: Good catch, skipeWhile does the job

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `filter`

```
this.store.select(state => this.list = state.list)
    .pipe(filter(x => !!x))
    .subscribe();
```

I prefer this mainly due to the similarity of the array.filter method.